# Android: converting String in Date

Tags: android, string, date

I try convert string date to other string date through Date object. But in runtime I've got exception about wrong PARSING. What is wrong with it?

```
String strDate= "Tue, 03 Sep 2013 12:45:23 +0300";
try{
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(strDate);
    strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm").format(d);
    System.out.println(strDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Russian locale. So I just need to point right locale:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String dtStart = "2013-09-02T17:40:36+00:00";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
 Date date;
try {  
   date = format.parse(dtStart);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}

SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM,dd yyyy HH:mm aa");  
try {  
 String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
 System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + datetime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: But I need exactly convert "Tue, 03 Sep 2013 12:45:23 +0300"

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");  
try {  
 String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
 System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + datetime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}`

Comment: In your code you took date (type Date) and converted in String. I need the opposite operation. I wrote about it in the top of question.

Comment: `String strDate = "Tue, 03 Sep 2013 12:45:23 +0300
";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");  
 Date date;
try {  
   date = format.parse(strDate);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}

SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm");  
try {  
 String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
 System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + datetime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}`

Comment: datetime variable value is what you need just copy paste the code...i took a String as you want converted into a Date type and then again converted back into a string of a format you want.

Comment: Thank you for your attention but as I said below just to be needed to point Locale.ENGLISH for parsing.